# RAP application with entrypoint path defined to "/" is not working on Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat7, ibm-was, eclipse-rap, contextroot

My RAP application has entrypoint defined following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.rap.ui.entrypoint">
      <entrypoint
            brandingId="com.ibm.kc.redirect.validator.rap.branding"                
            class="com.ibm.kc.redirect.validator.rap.app.ApplicationWorkbench"
            id="entrypoint"
            path="/">
      </entrypoint>
   </extension>
...
```

It works fine with `IBM WAS Liberty` but not on `Tomcat7`. Tomcat's context root is same as `name of war` in `webapps`. So when I access `localhost:8080/kc-redirect-tester` it should work.I defined entry point to "/" means `servlet path` after `context root` is only "/". I see lot of `404` where RWT resources going to `localhost:8080/`, like they had no idea of tomcat's context root.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tomcat7, http://127.0.0.1:8080/{appname}/
The appname must be the name of the war (eg. appname.war) and not the value of  in your web.xml servlet definition file. then add the context "/", => http://127.0.0.1:8080/{appname}**/** (don't forget the last "/")